# allocate time series interval to the column based on count of rows

Tags: r, dplyr

need to assaign time interval based on "cnt_rows" columns group by "Name".  i.e if count is around
96 means then it will be 15 mins time interval . so if count is 94 then time interval should stop at
11:15 PM (Based on number of rows) and if they are exactly 96 then it should end at 11:45 PM every day.
Same for 5 mins interval.  Interval should not exceed the day

```
cnt_rows = c("94","94",".",".","94","286","286",".",".",".","286","96","96",".",".","96")
Name = c("Alan","Alan",".",".","Alan","Steve","Steve",".",".",".","Steve","Mike","Mike",".",".","Mike")
Values = c("10","10",".",".","45","91","35",".",".",".","46","34","5",".",".","34")
```

Input Table

```
  df = data.frame(cnt_rows,Name,Values)
```

Output Table

```
dt = c("2019-12-01 00:00:00","2019-12-01 00:15:00",".",".","2019-12-01 23:15:00","2019-12-01 00:00:00","2019-12-01 00:05:00",".",".",".","2019-12-01 23:45:00","2019-12-01 00:00:00","2019-12-01 00:15:00",".",".","2019-12-01 23:45:00")

df_out = data.frame(cnt_rows,Name,Values,dt)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Could you explain when the data has to be divided in 15 mins interval and when it has to be divided in 5 mins interval?

Comment: If cnt_rows column are 94 or 96 then 15 Minutes and  if  cnt_rows column are 286 then 5 Minutes.Thanks @ronak

Comment: Do you have only 94, 96 and 286 values in the data? Nothing else?

Comment: Yes only  94, 96 and 286 values in the data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try :

```
library(dplyr)
date <- as.POSIXct('2019-12-01')

df %>%
  mutate(breaks = ifelse(cnt_rows %in% c(94, 96), '15 min', '5 min')) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(dt = seq(date, by = first(breaks), length.out = n()))
```

Comment: shaw ,  Thanks for your reply. creating interval with even seconds need to create with exact minute

Comment: @san1 Sorry, I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: @Shaw , I tried with actual data with 94  row count and expected time series is 15 mins while i ran data with above code intervel column (dt) generating with even second and if rows are 94 time series should shop at 11:15PM.Thanks